# Version control, Visual Studio and CodePlex

Tags: version-control, visual-studio

Maybe it's stupid question, but how to upload Visual Studio project to CodePlex.com? Only what I did is that I installed git plugin for VS. I'm searching in google, but cannot find simple tutorial about this. Is this that hard and cannot be described in simple steps?

Comment: Is there something wrong with this tutorial? http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20Git%20with%20CodePlex&referringTitle=Source%20Control

Comment: Thanks. It works. Still don't know how to tell VS2010 to use this :<

Comment: So ask about the specific step you're having trouble with, explain exactly what the problem is, and someone is likely to be able to help. It may be more on topic on StackOverflow though.

Comment: I installed git extension in visual studio and cannot find any new tool bars, new options or anything. Also I tried to connect File->Source Constrol, but I don't know any git address for codeplex :/